# Null pointer exception in setText() method of TextView

Tags: android

I have a gridView which i want to populate with my strings. But the problem arose when locating the TextView in which a particular string is to be printed.

I assigned the tags in XML using `android:tag` and now using the tag to find the corresponding TextView. But when i `setText()`, the app crashes giving NullPointerException.

Here is the code

```
public class OneDayTimeTable extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one_day_layout);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

        View view = new View(OneDayTimeTable.this);
        TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewWithTag("mon_11.30");
        tv.setText("Hi");


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/class_textView"
        android:text="Class: "
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/section_textView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Section: "
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/class_textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/date_textView"
        android:text="Date: "
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/date_textView"
    android:id="@+id/timetable_scroll_view">

    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="9"
        android:rowCount="6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="/"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10:30AM-11:30AM"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="11:30AM-12:15PM"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="12:15PM-1:15PM"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1:15PM-2:00PM"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2:00PM-3:00PM"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3:00PM-4:00PM"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4:00PM-5:00PM"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moday_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Monday"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Free"
            android:id="@+id/monday_10.30"
            android:tag="mon_10.30"

            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Free"
            android:id="@+id/monday_11.30"
            android:tag="mon_11.30"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="L"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Free"
            android:tag="mon_01.15"
            android:id="@+id/monday_1.15"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Free"
            android:tag="mon_02.00"
            android:id="@+id/monday_2.00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Free"
            android:tag="mon_03.00"
            android:id="@+id/monday_3.00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Free"
            android:tag="mon_04.00"
            android:id="@+id/monday_4.00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="8" />
    </GridLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tonystark.adminlogin/com.example.tonystark.adminlogin.OneDayTimeTable}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at com.example.tonystark.adminlogin.OneDayTimeTable.onCreate(OneDayTimeTable.java:37)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Maybe because `view.findViewWithTag("mon_11.30")` return null

Comment: problem is binding of TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setContentView(R.layout.one_day_layout); You can directly get the TextView using following line

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monday_11.30);
```

Now, this should work:

```
tv.setText("Hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  View view = new View(OneDayTimeTable.this);
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewWithTag("mon_11.30");
```

Your are creating an empty view and try to find a view in it :)

Comment: Ok. Lemme ask you straight ahead. I want to populate my gridview. I have gone with tags like "mon_10.30" as the format  <day>_<time>. This is lecture on monday at 10.30 am. Now I have my lecture subjects stored in a 2D array. I know that lecture[1][1] should be assigned to textView with tag "mon_10.30" but how to find that textview! I know i can directly refer to  the findViewById mthod and surely that will work like a charm but this will require me to make 6 days x6 lecture/day = 36 if-else cases. Any alternate method to do the same?